# Chrome Extension: Issues modifying a DOM element via content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm having issues modifying a DOM element on https://lichess.org/tv using a content-script. Eventually the goal is to display additional information [bellow the user name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyElb.png) (e.g. is he/she playing aggressive/defensive chess, ...) - for that reason I started by trying to change the user name:

```
targetNode[0].innerHTML = "test"
```

but it does not seem to have an effect for this particular element (I get the element though via the querySelector - verified with console.log()). When I try to change a other element on the site it works though:

```
const otherNode = document.querySelectorAll(".player > a");
otherNode[0].innerHTML = "othertest"
```

I'm new to developing extensions/javascript so I'm having a hard time figuring out what I'm doing worng here - any insights help. Thanks!

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "SomeExtension",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Description.",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "http://*.lichess.org/*", "https://*.lichess.org/*" ],
      "js": [ "content.js" ]
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**content.js**

```
console.log("Hello, World from content.js!");

//node(s) I want to change
const targetNode = document.querySelectorAll(".ruser > a");
console.log(targetNode[0].innerHTML);

targetNode[0].innerHTML = "test"

document.addEventListener('keypress', k);
function k(e) {
  console.log(`${e.code}`)
  targetNode[0].innerHTML = "test"
}

//other node where it works
const otherNode = document.querySelectorAll(".player > a");
otherNode[0].innerHTML = "othertest"
```

Comment: The page updates itself dynamically after your content script runs. Use MutationObserver to detect it and reapply your modifications if they're gone. Also don't assign to innerHTML of the page elements - it removes the event listeners attached by the site to the element's inner contents.

Comment: Another idea is that `.ruser > a` is recreated by the page so `targetNode` reference points to a useless detached node. Simply use `document.querySelector(".ruser > a")` everywhere (note, it's without [0]).

Comment: Thanks! The combination of using a mutation observer and using ```document.querySelector``` everywhere solved the issue for me.